# Choosing prefix name on creating new branch

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, branching-strategy, azure-repos

In our company, we use azure-devops and edited some settings about folder hierarchy (`hotfix`, `feature`, `bugfix` etc.) with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) documentation. 
[image: Create a branch popup]

We want to choose one of those prefix names and type branch name. For example, I choose feature and type login-page. Branch name will be `hotfix/login-page`. 
I search a lot but don't any result about that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I was looking for the same. BitBucket nicely gives options, e.g. feature/, hotfix/ with a custom option as well. Definitely, this is missing in Azure DevOps. I was so used to with BitBucket, after moving to Azure, most of the time I create branch without those prefixes and it's a mess now to manage. it's a greate feature to add to Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I choose feature and type login-page. Branch name will be
>   hotfix/login-page.

If you mean creating a branch name such as `hotfix/login-page`, then it's not supported. We can only select based on branch but cannot select the folder, that means we cannot create a branch based on a folder.

In your scenario, it will create a new branch called `login-page`branch under the `hotfix` folder.

That means `/` here will be identified as the symbol of the folder hierarchy.

If you want to create a branch under the feature folder, then you should type `feature/login-page`. We cannot select prefix name on creating a new branch.